# Angular 6 not able to render data on view

Tags: javascript, angular6

hello i am learning angular 6 and i am creating a simple app where i get data from API using Services Module and data is coming from API but when i try to display in view it gives error below is my code please help me what i am doing wrong.

**Comoponent**

```
export class LibraryComponent implements OnInit {

  users$: Object;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getLibrary().subscribe(
      data => this.users$ = data 
    );
  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<h1>{{users.artist.name}}</h1>
```

**API Data**

```
{
"artist":{
"name":"Bebe Rexha",
"mbid":"db8fad3a-e131-47a1-8782-c2ee93708cdd",
"url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Bebe+Rexha",
"image":[
{
"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/3c877e9871c5a1c6b23ba80c69e5cfb1.png",
"size":"small"
},
{
"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/3c877e9871c5a1c6b23ba80c69e5cfb1.png",
"size":"medium"
},
{
"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/3c877e9871c5a1c6b23ba80c69e5cfb1.png",
"size":"large"
},
{
"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/3c877e9871c5a1c6b23ba80c69e5cfb1.png",
"size":"extralarge"
},
{
"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/3c877e9871c5a1c6b23ba80c69e5cfb1.png",
"size":"mega"
},
{
"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/3c877e9871c5a1c6b23ba80c69e5cfb1.png",
"size":""
}
],
"streamable":"0",
```

**Error**

```
LibraryComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'artist' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (LibraryComponent.html:1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

users$ is undefined in your ts initially and on subscribing to the data from the observable it assigns a value to the users$ property.

```
<h1>{{users$?.artist.name}}</h1>
```

The ? here handles the undefined problem.

Comment: Thank u so much and how can i define  users so that no need use $? in html

Comment: The $ is just a convention used for properties that will result in an observable.

Comment: So just define users:object in your ts and in your html {{ users?.artist.name }}

Comment: and one last thing is how can i access image. #text from api data

Comment: because when i use # it gives this error > compiler.js:2427 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token #, expected identifier or keyword

Comment: Assuming you are using the ngFor="let img of users?.image" loop get the image using string interpolation by this workaround = {{ img["#text"] }} if ur using data binding then [src]="img["text"]". Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the assigning user to the "**users$**" variable but in the html you are referring to the wrong reference "**users**".

Please use `?` **safe navigation operator** of angular. it will not throw any error if value is not available.

```
<h1>{{users$?.artist?.name}}</h1>
```